# Special characters conversion from service in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa, unicode, foundation, chinese-locale

I am getting some data from response which includes some special characters. The text is in Chinese format. Here I have shown the special characters.

Please have a look and advise me how to convert this to Chinese format. It is possible in android using this method

```
String s = "hhh"; 
s.getBytes("Windows-1252");
```

Special Characters string is

```
"P.R. China 100020 ä¸­å›½åŒ—äº¬å¸‚æœé˜³åŒºæœå¤–å¤§è¡—22å·æ³›åˆ©å   
¤§åŽ¦408å®¤"
```

Comment: Its original text is 中国成都市锦江区东大街紫东楼段11号东方广场A座2203室

Comment: Is that What's your language? What's with all these iOS tags?

Comment: The mentioned string is returned as response from DB while accessing as web service.

Comment: As a advice from my friend I followed Windows 1252 encoding technique for that data.but its not working.

Comment: `NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)? Could you show more code?

Comment: <address>Room 408 Prime Tower, No.22, Chaowai Street,
Chaoyang District, Beijing , P.R. China 100020

ä¸­å›½åŒ—äº¬å¸‚æœé˜³åŒºæœå¤–å¤§è¡—22å·æ³›åˆ©å¤§åŽ¦408å®¤</address>

Comment: This is the response from service.O want to convert that string into above mentioned chineese format.